# div append text with an animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this has been asked a few times around here but most of the answers didn't solve for the case where one could consistently append information and the box was visible to begin with (and I don't know the new height I would like to animate to (because its text im adding))

Say I have a div and I append text to it how would I animate it

```
<div id="mybox">
Text
</div>
```

Javascript code (JQuery library is used)

```
function appendAndAnimate(text)
    $('#mybox').append(text +"<br/>")
end
```

I want to call this a couple of times and not have it jerk to the new height but slowly expand to it. (The box isn't hidden to begin with or anything).
I've tried `-webkit-transition` and `transition` to no avail. I've also played around with capturing the height before and after and shifting it back and forth but theres no elegance here and its more a dirty solution

Because its text I wouldn't like to use a flat on add a height with animation to the div box because people may have different font-scaling set on their browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understood you want to make animation of `mybox` when you append text. I can see it like adding a new block of text into `mybox` and showing it with `slideDown` animation as an example. Then it will look like that:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var el = $("<div />").css("display", "none").text("New Text")
    $("#mybox").append(el);
    el.slideDown(1000);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YRuqP/

---

**UPDATE.** In fact I have even better solution. If you don't want to add blocks of text. You can use another variant. Here we need to add one extra block inside `mybox`, so the markup will look like this:

```
<div id="mybox">
    <div>
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

And set to `mybox` style `overflow: hidden`.

Then we can update the code a bit to have nice sliding animation when any piece of text is inserted.

```
var block = $("#mybox");
var child = block.children();
block.css("height", block.height());

$("button").click(function() {
    child.append(text);
    block.animate({
        height: child.height()
    });
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YRuqP/1/